# uninitialized constant Admin::CommentsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are posts and few other resources with comments (polymorphic associations)

> ActionController::RoutingError at **/admin/posts/1/comments/new**

routes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

.

```
<%= link_to "Comment", [:new, @commentable, :comment] %>
```

posts_controller

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @post
  @comments = @commentable.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you don't have `Admin::CommentsController` i.e., `CommentsController` should be under `Admin` namespace.

For example: `CommentsController` class should be defined as:

```
class Admin::CommentsController < ApplicationController
   .....
end
```

Also, place `comments_controller.rb` under `app/controllers/admin` directory.